# Android-Two toggle buttons in list view, its working like radio button

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, togglebutton, radio-group

My requirement:-
Questions with choose options, options are 'Yes, No, NoResult'. The options names are dunamically loaded corresponding to the question. So this option is available on toggle button and radio button in android.
But radion button occupies spase highly, toggle button is better for me.

Want to list out the questions with two toggle buttons(options) in listview. - Completed.
For example:-
1. First toggle button- "Yes"
2. Second toggle button - "No"

Conditions:-
1. If click the first toggle button-'ON', second toggle button should be in 'OFF' its like vice versa. 
2. But can not be done through programmatically.
3. Please share your ideas to achieve the function.

Summary:-
Want to work with 2 toggle button like radion button.

Regards,
Naresh T

Answer (score 1):

Try this code by Guillaume Beraudo:

```
    /*
ToggleImageButton.java
Copyright (C) 2010  Belledonne Communications, Grenoble, France

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307, USA.
*/
package com.home.automation;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Checkable;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

/**
 * Image button storing a checked state to display alternating drawables.
 * The "checked" drawable is displayed when button is down / checked.
 * The "unchecked" drawable is displayed when button is up / unchecked.
 *
 * @author Guillaume Beraudo
 *
 */
public class ToggleImageButton extends ImageButton implements Checkable, OnClickListener{

    private boolean checked;
    private Drawable stateChecked;
    private Drawable stateUnChecked;
    private boolean drawablesForBackground;
    private OnCheckedChangeListener onCheckedChangeListener;

    public ToggleImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ToggleImageButton);
        stateChecked = getResources().getDrawable(array.getResourceId(R.styleable.ToggleImageButton_checked, -1));
        stateUnChecked = getResources().getDrawable(array.getResourceId(R.styleable.ToggleImageButton_unchecked, -1));
        drawablesForBackground = array.getBoolean(R.styleable.ToggleImageButton_bgdrawables, false);
        setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        setOnClickListener(this);
        handleCheckChanged();
    }



    /**
     * @return the stateChecked
     */
    public Drawable getStateChecked() {
        return stateChecked;
    }



    /**
     * @param stateChecked the stateChecked to set
     */
    public void setStateChecked(Drawable stateChecked) {
        this.stateChecked = stateChecked;
    }



    /**
     * @return the stateUnChecked
     */
    public Drawable getStateUnChecked() {
        return stateUnChecked;
    }



    /**
     * @param stateUnChecked the stateUnChecked to set
     */
    public void setStateUnChecked(Drawable stateUnChecked) {
        this.stateUnChecked = stateUnChecked;
    }



    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        this.checked = checked;
        handleCheckChanged();
    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return checked;
    }


    private void handleCheckChanged() {
        Drawable d = checked? stateChecked : stateUnChecked;
        if (drawablesForBackground) {
            setBackgroundDrawable(d);
        } else {
            setImageDrawable(d);
        }
        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
        if (onCheckedChangeListener != null) onCheckedChangeListener.onCheckedChanged(this, checked);
    }


    public void setOnCheckedChangeListener(OnCheckedChangeListener listener) {
        onCheckedChangeListener = listener;
    }

    public static interface OnCheckedChangeListener {
        void onCheckedChanged(ToggleImageButton button, boolean checked);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        toggle();
    }


    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!isChecked());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        toggle();
        return super.performClick();
    }

}
```

Now to enable radio group like functionality write a class like this:

```
    public class CustomMenuItem extends LinearLayout {
    private ToggleImageButton menuImage;
    private TextView menuText;
    private Context context;
    int resId;
    int resId_Pressed;
    int light = 0;
    private String name;

    public CustomMenuItem(Context context, int resId, int resId_Pressed,int light){
        this(context, null);
        this.context = context;
        this.resId = resId;
        this.resId_Pressed = resId_Pressed;
        this.light = light;
    }

    public CustomMenuItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomMenuItem(Context context2, int resId, int resId_Pressed,String areaName) {
        this(context2, null);
        this.context = context2;
        this.resId = resId;
        this.resId_Pressed = resId_Pressed;
        this.name = areaName;
    }

    public LinearLayout getCustomView(){
        LayoutInflater menuItemInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout menuLayout = (LinearLayout) menuItemInflater.inflate(R.layout.menuitem, null); 
        menuImage = (ToggleImageButton) menuLayout.findViewById(R.id.menuimage);
        menuImage.setStateChecked(getResources().getDrawable(resId_Pressed));
        menuImage.setStateUnChecked(getResources().getDrawable(resId));
        menuImage.setChecked(false);
        menuText = (TextView) menuLayout.findViewById(R.id.menutext);
        if(light == 0 && name != null)
            menuText.setText(name);
        else
            menuText.setText(light);
        return menuLayout;
    }
}
```

In your XML add CustomMenuItem as Layout and add ToggleImageButton to it. You might need to make certain improvements in CustomMenuItem class to handle single selection out of many. For this you can follow this simple approach:
- When an ToggleImageButton is clicked iterate through the list of buttons and mark the given ID as selected rest as not selected. This if going to be a very simple logic. Give it a try.

All the best.